# Telegram source code String file changing no effect

Tags: java, xml, telegram

I have downloaded telegram source code from official GitHub page and I have changed the strings.xml and logo, app name etc and I compiled the same. But when I first open the app it shows by changed string and after logging in the strings will be shown as in the source ( my changes are not effected). Why this strings get reseted back to initial values

Comment: 1) rebuild the project. 2) search the text in the project (source codes) and change it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.